# I changed the php 5.6 version to php 8.1 in cPanel. Now facing issue of "Call to undefined function curl_init()". How to solve this problem?

Tags: curl, codeigniter-3

My Hosting server is on linux. I changed php 5.6 to php 8.1 version. But after this cUrl() not work for my codeigniter website. Generates error "Call to undefined function curl_init()". How to solve this problem. Is any package needed to install. If yes then How? Please give the step by step guide for to resolve this issue.

I searched a lot on google. But not get proper solution about this issue. For few search I got the solution about to install cUrl library. But did not get any explanation about commands on linux and on which terminal needs to perform this commands? On desktop terminal or linux server or through cPanel?

Please guide about it

Answer (score 0):

your php 8.1 is missing the package curl
you have to update the packages type :

```
apt-get update -y
```

or

```
yum update -y
```

after that check if the packages like this :

```
apt-cache search php8.1-curl
```

you will have like this :

```
php8.1-curl - CURL module for PHP
```

Comment: How to use "apt-get update -y" this command to update packages? Means where to execute this command. Give step-by-step guidance about the command. Please start your explanation through command prompt. Means how to open command prompt on cPanel?

Comment: I am new to this type of issues. Never used any linux command prompts before.

Comment: you can use Terminal SSH to execute those commands , you have to have a server or vps and you have permissions to open SSH ( default port is 22 ) .
you have to use program like Puty or bitvise SSH client and entered your Server's IP Address and your root ( or user pass )

Answer (score 0):

Provisioning the curl services in Cpanel via Easy Apache works up to PHP 8.3. Past Date actions for wordpress as well as Wordfence rules refresh are now functioning perfectly. Thank you!